# Is a set with the form $\bigcup_{i,j\in I}U_i\times V_j$ an element of the base of the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Given $(X,\tau)$ a top. manifold, consider an open set $O\in\tau^2$(in the product topology of $X\times X$) with the form

$$O=\bigcup_{i,j\in I}U_i\times V_j$$

(note that not every open set has this form).

Is it true that $O=\text{Dom }O\times\text{Im } O$?

Here is my proof:

\begin{align}
O&=\bigcup_{i,j\in I}U_i\times V_j \\
&=\bigcup_{i\in I}(\bigcup_{j\in I}U_i\times V_j) \\
&=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times(\bigcup_{j\in I}V_j)) \\
&=\bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i\times\text{Im }O) \\
&=(\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i)\times\text{Im }O \\
&=\text{Dom }O\times\text{Im }O
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Instead of $O=\text{Dom }O\times\text{Im }O$ one could say equivalently that $O=A\times B$ for some $A,B\in\tau$.

**Edit:**

$\text{Im}O=\{y\mid \exists x:(x,y)\in O\}$ and $\text{Dom}O=\{x\mid \exists y:(x,y)\in O\}=\text{Im}O^T$.

Comment: What is $\text{Dom}(O)$ and $\text{Im}(O)$?

Comment: So what you're saying is that all open sets are rectangles? The unit disc will be very *very* sorry to hear that.

Comment: How is $\text{Dom}(O)$ defined?

Comment: That is not a general open set. It's the union of every possible product of two families of sets.. and so yes, i think this holds. The unit ball is not a set of this kind.

Comment: Clearly a general open set is of the form $\bigcup A_j \times B_j$ and this is not, in general, a rectangle. Different is the situation where we take $\bigcup _{i,j} A_j \times B_i$

Comment: Minor note: $τ^2$ is the product topology for $X × X$ for you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Your equalities all work perfectly.